# How to link social media when clicked media icon SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, deep-linking

Im trying to make a link when user click social media icons . How can I do that with SwiftUI. I couldn't find any source for that .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it:

**First:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Link(destination: URL(string: "")!) // <- Add your link here
        {
            Image(systemName: "link.circle.fill") // <- Change icon to your preferred one
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

**Second:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            openURL(URL(string: "")!) // <- Add your link here
        }, label: {
           Image(systemName: "link.circle.fill") // <- Change icon to your preferred one 
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using Link which designed for this job?